# Not able to get the coordinates of a particular window (I've tried the examples...still ) in V C++

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I have been trying various code snippets here and there, but still not successful.I am simply trying to find one of the open windows (it is the Browser window) using `FindWindow(NULL,WINDOWTITLE)`, with a specific Title string. Once I get the handle of the window, I need the coordinates using `GetWindowRect`.

This code gets me the coordinates, but seems like it's in an infinite loop, there are about a 100 lines of output with the coordindates, should be just 1. I don't see any while construct (originally a Java programmer)... wonder why it's repeating...

```
struct WindowInfo
{
  HWND m_hWnd;
  string m_title;
  WindowInfo(HWND hwnd, string title) : m_hWnd(hwnd), m_title(title) {}
};

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd,LPARAM lParam)
{
  vector<WindowInfo*> & windows = *(vector<WindowInfo*>*)lParam;
  char title[256];

  HANDLE wndHandle;
  LPCWSTR WINDOWTITLE = L"eBargain 2 Share - Windpos Internet Explorer";
  RECT rRect;
  LPRECT lpRect;
  RECT rc;

  hwnd = FindWindow(NULL,WINDOWTITLE);  

  GetWindowRect(hwnd,&rc);
  printf("Position: %d x %d\tSize: %d x %d\n",rc.left,rc.top,rc.right- rc.left,rc.bottom-rc.top);

       /* Enumerating through all the windows tells me that I am on the right    track... (Should I just try to find the TITLE STRING by comparing every title from the following enumeration ?  
       */
      GetWindowTextA(hwnd, title, 256);
    windows.push_back(new WindowInfo(hwnd,title));
   //  printf("%s\n", title);
    return TRUE;

}
int main()
{
  vector<WindowInfo*> windows;
  BOOL ret = EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, (LPARAM) &windows);
  if ( ret )
  {
      //windows have windowinfo of all enumerated windows
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `EnumWindowsProc` seems to be a bit confused - are you enumerating or using `FindWindow`?

If you enumerate, simply get the window title and compare to the string you search for:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd,LPARAM lParam)
{
  char title[256];
  if (GetWindowTextA(hwnd, title, 256)) {
    if (strcmp(title, "eBargain 2 Share - Windpos Internet Explorer") == 0) {
      /* GetWindowRect ... */
    }
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

Or, if you're using `FindWindow`, no need to enumerate:

```
int main() {
  HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(0, "eBargain 2 Share - Windpos Internet Explorer");
  if (hwnd) {
    /* GetWindowRect ... */      
  }    
}
```

Comment: One minor addition to the EnumWindowsProc version: if you just want the first match, then return FALSE once you find the one you want and are ready to return, and the enumeration will stop. If you return TRUE, windows will keep enumerating in case there are any further matches. (This can be useful in cases where multiple windows have the same name, and you need to do additional tests to find out which is the one you want.)